# How do I turn AsyncSnapshot data into a Map?

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, dart

I want to get some json data in my FutureBuilder but for some reason my code throws a
`_TypeError (type '_JsonQuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>')`
whenever I try to unpack the AsyncSnapshot into a Map.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
    future: getFiyat(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
            lists.clear();

            // type error is thrown here
            Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data;

            values.forEach((key, values) {
                lists.add(values);
            });
        }

        return ListView.builder();
    },
);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What **exactly** is `getFiyat()` returning?

Answer (score 0):

You have your `QuerySnapshot data` and you should call `data()` on this snapshot, to get its content. In your case:

```
QuerySnapshot<Object?>? querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = querySnapshot.data();
```

Comment: The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'. I got this error

Comment: Oh, I forgot that this is Query, not Document. QuerySnapshot provides you list of DocumentReferences. to get data from DocumentReference, you need another async future, like querySnapshot.forEach(( doc ) async { Map<String, dynamic> value = await doc.get() })